# Convert plain string to JSON and back in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

Let's say there's a JSON-string I got from server: **"\"3\""** (with quotes, i.e. length == 3 here)

In Android-world, I can do:

`gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<String>() {}.getType());` - it returns  **"3"** (i.e. length == 1)

In C#-world, can use NewtonSoft.Json:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json, settings)` - it returns **"3"** (i.e. length == 1)

And other way around, I do have string I want to serialize as a JSON.
In Android I'd do `gson.toJson("\"3\"")` and in C# - `JsonConvert.SerializeObject("\"3\"")`

The problem with JSONSerialization is that it doesn't treat plain string as a valid JSON: `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject("\"3\"") == *false*`

**What would be equivalent in Swift / Obj-C world?**

The ugly **workaround** I've found (except of just adding/removing quotes) so far is to wrap string into 1-item-array to make `JSONSerialization` happy and then remove "[","]" from resulted JSON-string (and other way around - add "[", "]" before deserialization), but it's a way too disgusting to be the  real solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When de-serializing JSON which does not have an array or
dictionary as top-level object you can pass the
`.allowFragments` option:

```
let jsonString =  "\"3\""
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments)

if let str = json as? String {
    print(str) // 3
}
```

However, there seems to be no way to *serialize* a plain string to JSON
with the `JSONSerialization` class from the Foundation library.

Note that according to the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org),
a JSON object is a collection of name/value pairs (dictionary) or
an ordered list of values (array). A single string is not a valid
JSON object.